# Concurrent control of generator and subroutine in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, generator, coroutine

Function `bigop(init, report)` operates on a large dynamic internal data structure `data` derived from `init`, and accepts a callable `report(data)`. Function `status(data)` returns a summary of the current state of `data`.

Function `bigop` calls `report` on the current state of `data` at each major step, which in turn calls `status`. It would be expensive to copy `data` for each step (or make it persistent), so `report` must finish at each step before `bigop` continues.

Function `view(gen)` accepts a generator `gen` yielding successive values of the status summary, and displays a visualization of each value as it is generated. The function `view` maintains internal state dependent on values generated thus far. (In my particular case, this internal state *could* be copied, but it would be nice to avoid.)

Assume that functions `bigop` and `view` cannot be changed.

Question: how can one define `gen`, `report`, and a program `main` such that `bigop` will run on `init`, and visualizations of the values of the status reports will be displayed *as* `bigop` reaches each major step?

The difficulty lies in that `report` and `gen` are called inside other functions, so the usual Python coroutine patterns are inapplicable. (In my particular case, `bigop` is actually a generator.)

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968592/turn-functions-with-a-callback-into-python-generators?rq=1) about using callbacks to produce generators from ordinary functions was answered using threads, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way.

Note: only answers compatible with Python 2.7 will be useful to me; but I would be interested to see Python 3 answers if the differences are relevant.

```
def bigop(init, report):
    data = init
    while data < 10:           # complicated condition
        print 'working ...'
        data += 1              # complicated operation
        report(data)

def view(gen):
    for value in gen:
        print value            # complicated display routine

def main(init):
    """
    example:

    >> main(7)
    'working ...'
    8
    'working ...'
    9
    'working ...'
    10
    """
    pass
```

Question: how to define `main`?

Comment: It's hard to understand your design from these descriptions. Can you write an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), with simple examples that demonstrate what you're doing, so you can point at it and say, "And every time this line runs, I want this code over here to do that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample code:

```
def main(init):
    def report(x):
        print x
    bigop(init, report)
```

However, I don't think that's what you're looking for here. Presumably you want `report` to feed data into `view` in some way.

You can do that by turning things around—instead of `view` being a generator that drives another generator, it's a generator that's driven by an outside caller calling `send` on it. For example:

```
def view():
    while True:
        value = yield
        print value
def main(init):
    v = view()
    v.next()
    def report(x):
        v.send(x)
    bigop(init, report)
```

But you said that `view` can't be changed. Of course you can write a `viewdriver` that `yield`s a new object whenever you `send` it one. Or, more simply, just repeatedly call `view([data])` and let it iterate over a single object.

Anyway, I don't see how you expect this to help anything. `bigop` is not a coroutine, and you cannot turn it into one. Given that, there's no way to force it to cooperatively share with other coroutines.

If you want to interleave processing and reporting concurrently, you have to use threads (or processes). And the fact that "REPORT must finish at each step before BIGOP continues" is already part of your requirements implies that you can't safely do anything concurrent here anyway, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

If you just want to interleave processing and reporting *without* concurrency—or periodically hook into `bigop`, or other similar things—you *can* do that with a coroutine, but it will have exactly the same effect as using a subroutine—the two examples above are pretty much equivalent. So, you're just adding complexity for no reason.

(If `bigop` is I/O bound, you could use greenlets, and monkeypatch the I/O operations to asyncify them, as `gevent` and `eventlet` do. But if it's CPU-bound, there would be no benefit to doing so.)

---

Elaborating on the `viewdriver` idea: What I was describing above was equivalent to calling `view([data])` each time, so it won't help you. If you want to make it an iterator, you can, but it's just going to lead to either blocking `bigop` or spinning `view`, because you're trying to feed a consumer with a consumer.

It may be hard to understand as a generator, so let's build it as a class:

```
class Reporter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_queue = []
        self.viewer = view(self)
    def __call__(self, data):
        self.data_queue.append(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return self.data_queue.pop()

bigop(init, Reporter())
```

Every time `bigop` calls `report(data)`, that calls our `__call__`, adding a new element to our queue. Every time `view` goes through the loop, it calls our `__next__`, popping an element off the queue. If `bigop` is guaranteed to go faster than `view`, everything will work, but the first time `view` gets ahead, it will get an `IndexError`.

The only way to fix that is to make `__next__` try until `data_queue` is non-empty. But just doing that will spin forever, not letting `bigop` do the work to produce a new element. And you can't make `__next__` into a generator, because `view` is expecting an iterator over values, not an iterator over iterators.

Fortunately, `__call__` can be a generator, because `bigop` doesn't care what value it gets back. So, you can turn things around. But you can't do that, because then there's nothing to drive that generator.

So, you have to add another level of coroutines, underneath the iteration. Then, `__next__` can wait on a `next_coro` (by calling `next` on it), which yields to a `call_coro` and then yields the value it got. Meanwhile, `__call__` has to `send` to the same `call_coro`, wait on it, and yield.

So far, that doesn't change anything, because you've got two routines both trying to drive `next_coro`, and one of them (`__next__`) isn't blocking anywhere else, so it's just going to spin—it's `next` call will look like a `send(None)` from `__call__`.

The only way to fix that is to build a trampoline ([PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) includes source for a general-purpose trampoline, although in this case you could build a simpler special-purpose one), schedule `next_coro` and `call_coro` to explicitly alternate, make sure `next_coro` properly handles alternating between two different entry points, then drive the scheduler's `run` from `__next__` (and `__init__`).

Confused? You won't be, after this week's episode of… Nah, who am I kidding. You're going to be confused. Writing all of this is one thing; debugging it is another. (Especially since every important stack trace just terminates immediately at the trampoline.) And what does all that work get you? The exact same benefit as using greenlets or threads, with the exact same downsides.

Since your original question is whether there's a simpler way than using threads, the answer is: No, there isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. My short summary is that: no, there is no simpler way in Python than using threads.  
  
I didn't quite understand what you meant about a `viewdriver`, but the issue with using separate calls `view([data])` is that `view` also has internal state (I have edited the question to reflect this).

Comment: Were the definitions of `bigop` and `view` not already fixed, your other suggestions would certainly work, but I wondered if there was a way to effectively wrap `gen` so that `view` would proceed on it only when new values were generated.

Comment: Let me edit the answer to explain more about the `viewdriver` idea… but I don't think it will help you, and your short summary is right. You've got one component that expects to be on a push chain, and another that expects to be on a pull chain, and you can't change either.